# Does this method violate c# syntax rules? would it be considered a syntax error?

Tags: c#, validation, methods

I wrote this code for a windows form application.This is one of the event handlers for a button click.

```
private void btnLP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isValidData()
    {
        return
            IsPresent(txtLoanAmountLP) &&
            IsPresent(txtInterstLP) &&
            IsPresent(txtYearsLP) &&
            IsDecimal(txtLoanAmountLP) &&
            IsDecimal(txtInterstLP) &&
            IsDecimal(txtYearsLP) &&
            IsWithinRange(txtLoanAmountLP, 1, 999999) &&
            IsWithinRange(txtInterstLP, 1, 18) &&
            IsWithinRange(txtYearsLP, 1, 30);
    }

    try
    {
        if (isValidData())
        {
            double Loan = Convert.ToDouble(txtLoanAmountLP.Text);
            double IR = Convert.ToDouble(txtInterstLP.Text);
            int yrs = Convert.ToInt32(txtYearsLP.Text);

            double MP = CalcLP(Loan, IR, yrs);
            txtMonthlyPaymentLP.Text = MP.ToString("c");

            txtLoanAmountLP.SelectAll();
            txtLoanAmountLP.Focus();
            totalCal++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() +
                        "\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
    }
}
```

My instructor claims there is a syntax error, which I can't find. I thought the program couldn't even be compiled if there were syntax errors. She said the problem was that I have a void method returning a value. Are my void methods (the event handlers for button clicks) incorrect somehow?

Comment: Note that even *if* it were true that you had a void method returning value, which you don't, then this would *still* be *semantic* error, not a syntactic one.

Comment: I bet you that your instructor 1. Is wrong. 2. Sees your nested function isValidData() returning a value and does not realized it is nested. I suspect this because that is how I read it to start (I rarely use C#). Your code looks correct - I assume it compiles correctly. If it compiles then there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no syntax error.

Your instructor is probably concerned about this portion, which appears within a method with a void return:

```
bool isValidData()
{
    return
        IsPresent(txtLoanAmountLP) &&
        IsPresent(txtInterstLP) &&
        IsPresent(txtYearsLP) &&
        IsDecimal(txtLoanAmountLP) &&
        IsDecimal(txtInterstLP) &&
        IsDecimal(txtYearsLP) &&
        IsWithinRange(txtLoanAmountLP, 1, 999999) &&
        IsWithinRange(txtInterstLP, 1, 18) &&
        IsWithinRange(txtYearsLP, 1, 30);
}
```

This is of course a C#7 local function, which were recently introduced. You might tell her (with appropriate politeness and humility, since you are the student) to read this: [What's new in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions)

Comment: Thanks! is it possible that she is using an outdated version of visual studios which shows a syntax error? I don't understand why she would be seeing one.

Comment: It is likely she is using an older version, yes. As instructor she should probably tell her students which version of framework, runtime, and C# compiler y'all should be using, so that results are consistent.

Comment: There is no syntax error *depending on the c# version you're using...*